# Why did the Devil's Triangle only curse the crew of the Silent Mary?

Tags: pirates-of-the-caribbean, dead-men-tell-no-tales

Why did the Devil's triangle curse only Captain Salazar and his crew? Surely there were previous ships that entered the triangle before this. What happened to them?

Even Henry's ship enters the triangle but is unaffected by it. Why?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wikia](http://pirates.wikia.com/wiki/Devil%27s_Triangle#cite_note-DMTNT-0):

> According to legends, many of the ships that entered these waters vanished without warning or explanation, leaving only a few lucky sailors to recount the monsters, storms, ghosts, and pirates responsible for their misfortunes.

But it's also mentioned that:

> However, the supernatural forces in the Triangle revived Salazar and his crew as powerful ghosts, granting them vast powers and abilities, though keeping them imprisoned within the Triangle for decades to come.

So we are to buy that **some supernatural** explanation.

Comment: To add to this, Salazar is directly connected to Jack's compass. The **exact** second Jack "betrays the compass" (which he was warned not to do), Salazar is freed from the triangle and starts hunting Jack. Salazar, his crew and the Silent Mary may have been kept alive specifically because of the magic of the compass.

Comment: Salazar's connection to Jack's compass and how Salazar knew that Jack gave away his compass is totally different **[discussion](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/74649/how-is-salazars-curse-linked-with-sparrows-compass)**

Comment: How can you be sure it's unrelated? Your answer ends on "supernatural", and the compass' magic is also supernatural (by definition of "magic"). There is no proof that they are conclusively connected, but it's still possible. Occam's Razor suggests that a connection is likely, because otherwise Salazar is connected to two completely unrelated supernatural occurrences (his undead form + his connection to the compass) for two completely unrelated reasons.

Comment: @Flater: What I mean to say is until there is a next movie which gives explanation to all this. Till now it's unexplained.

Comment: @Rahul: "... there is a next movie which gives explanation to all this" - any sources to back this up?

Comment: @bobbyalex: You missed the word **until**.

Comment: Ah... my bad! Selective reading.

Answer (score 1):

The Devils Traingle is a geological location with supernatural properties that was,

> ... A place where the **dead live and the living die**, the Triangle
>   was avoided by every sailor worth his salt.

---

> Salazar's ship, the Silent Mary, was almost completely destroyed in a
>   series of explosions, which caused the deaths of Salazar and all his
>   men. **However, the supernatural forces in the Triangle revived Salazar
>   and his crew as powerful ghosts**, granting them vast powers and
>   abilities, though **keeping them imprisoned within the Triangle** for
>   decades to come.
>
> http://pirates.wikia.com/wiki/Devil%27s_Triangle

Everyone who enters the triangle basically becomes "cursed" similar to what we have seen throughout *Pirates of the Caribbean* films, most notitably with Brabossa's crew in *Curse of the Black Pearl*.

> Many years later, a down on his luck Jack Sparrow traded his compass
>   away for a bottle of rum **he incurred a terrible price**. For
>   dishonorably trading the compass away the thing he feared most,
>   Armando **Salazar and his crew were set free**; the entire Triangle
>   shattering and sinking to allow them their freedom.

However, the reason Salazar has escaped, is because of an **additional curse** that relates to Salazar through Jack's compass by "betraying it", causing *'the thing he [currently] fears most'* to come true.

So it seems likley that others WERE trapped as cursed 'living-dead' ghosts in the Triangle, and probably most were not be able to leave, but considering the Triangle sank, it seems likely the others [who could not escape] sank with it and it's unlcear then if they remianed living-dead trapped under the ocean or if the magic/curse was broken (by the destruction of the Trident) and they "passed onto" the other side?