# Why isn't Jack Sparrow's greatest fear released before?

Tags: plot-explanation, pirates-of-the-caribbean, dead-men-tell-no-tales

In *Pirates of the Carribean: Dead Men Tells no Tales* Jack Sparrow exchanges his compass for drink. As it happens it is told that the compass is
betrayed and his greatest fear is released. But before this he gives away the compass many times. He gives it away to Will Turner and Elizabeth Swann also. So why wasn't these actions considered as betraying the compass? Why didn't then his greatest fear was released?

Comment: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/74649/how-is-salazars-curse-linked-with-sparrows-compass
Please read the post, It discusses same argument exhaustively, especially TheLethalCarrot 's answer

Answer (score 2):

> But before this he gives away the compass many times. He gives it away to Will Turner and Elizabeth Swann also. So why wasn't these actions considered as betraying the compass? Why didn't then his greatest fear was released?

Never forget that most curses and enchantments tend to be omniscient to handwave inconsistencies or the ability to "lie" to a curse.

In the instances you reference, Jack is not giving it away so much as he is loaning it to someone. It remains his compass, and he'll want it back.

But in DMTNT, he **sells** the compass, therefore giving up ownership over it.

We can argue about details like if renting the compass out would count or not, but the point remains that there is a clear difference in DMTNT whereby Jack intends to transfer *ownership* of the compass, rather than letting someone else physically carry it.